# If a request is made from the front end, which ip address is doing the request?

Tags: api, request, frontend, ip-address

If a request is made from the front end, which ip address is doing the request? Is it the server running the front end application or the user using the site?

If on the front end code you have code that calls an api to a third party service. Which IP adderess registers as the one that has made the request. The server hosting the front end site or the user using the site?

Comment: it is the users IP address

Comment: Just to add a little more information... if the request was an Ajax call from a website running JavaScript, the code is running in the users browser, so the request comes directly from there. If its from a mobile application, the request comes from the users phone, so will either be their mobile data IP address or their Wifi address.

Comment: So there is no scenario that the request comes from the server that served the front end?

Comment: not unless the front end is designed to receive and proxy the requests to the backend, no. not any that i can think of